# Unexpected Behavior in `Sum[a + Subscript[a, 1], {a, 1, 2}]`

Tags: variable-definitions

The simple command

```
Sum[a + Subscript[a, 1], {a, 1, 2}]
```

gives the unexpected result

```
4 + Subscript[2, 1]
```

while what I want is $3+2a_1$.

I think the problem is due to the unwanted subsitution of $a_1$ while summing over $a$. How can I resolve this problem, by not changing the variable name? (The actual expression that I want to evaluate is much more complicated.)

Comment: Which version are you on? Is this with a fresh kernel without definitions of a?

Comment: @SHuisman I am in 12.1 and the kernel is fresh without any definition of `a`.

Comment: Use ```Subscript[HoldForm[a],1]```. The result you get is not unexpected.

Comment: also `Sum[a + Subscript[Defer@a, 1], {a, 1, 2}]` and `Sum[a + Defer@Subscript[a, 1], {a, 1, 2}]`

Comment: I mean, why not do `Sum[x + Subscript[a, 1], {x, 1, 2}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the problem where structural elements (e.g., [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript)) that contain the solve variable prevent functions like [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum), [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve), etc. from working, you can do the following:

```
Unprotect[Sum];
Sum[e__] /; !FreeQ[Hold[e], _Subscript] := Block[{CompressedData},
    With[{res = Sum @@ ReplaceAll[{e}, s_Subscript :> CompressedData[Compress@s]]}, 
        res /; !MatchQ[res, _Sum]
    ]
]
Protect[Sum];
```

The above code temporarily converts the subscript to a string, then performs the sum, then restores the subscript. For your example:

```
Sum[a + Subscript[a, 1], {a, 1, 2}]
```

> 3 + 2 Subscript[a, 1]

Answer (score 4):

The `HoldForm[]` command shall "hold" the "form" of the argument it takes, without substituting that argument with the value you might have assigned to the argument variable elsewhere.

`Sum[a + Subscript[HoldForm[a], 1], {a, 1, 2}]`

gives the result you wish to get.

If you wish to get rid of the `HoldForm` action on a variable later on, use `ReleaseHold`.